# sql crosstab for graphing data output

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a crosstab of data so that the columns are months of the year and the rows are the years themselves based on value sold in that month.

Therefore:

year jan feb mar apr etc
2014   0  1   5   9
2015   11 12  0   14

using this SQL - (excuse the crudeness)

```
SELECT distinct 
case 
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2014 then 2014
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2015 then 2015
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2016 then 2016
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2017 then 2017
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2018 then 2018
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2019 then 2019
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2020 then 2020
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2021 then 2021
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2022 then 2022
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2023 then 2023
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2024 then 2024
when year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) = 2025 then 2025
end as Month1,
(select sum(cast(fsivl.ShipQuantity * fsivl.InvoiceLocalUnitPrice as decimal(8,2))) as Value
from sqlinvline  fsivl , sqlinvheaher  fsivh
where fsivl.HeaderKey = fsivh.HeaderKey
and fsivh.InvoiceType = 'I' 
and year(fsivh.InvoiceDate)* 100 + month(fsivh.InvoiceDate)
= year(fsivho.InvoiceDate)* 100 + month(fsivho.InvoiceDate)
and MONTH(fsivh.InvoiceDate) = 1
) as 'Jan',
(select sum(cast(fsivl.ShipQuantity * fsivl.InvoiceLocalUnitPrice as decimal(8,2))) as Value
from sqlinvline  fsivl , sqlinvheaher  fsivh
where fsivl.HeaderKey = fsivh.HeaderKey
and fsivh.InvoiceType = 'I' 
and year(fsivh.InvoiceDate)* 100 + month(fsivh.InvoiceDate)
= year(fsivho.InvoiceDate)* 100 + month(fsivho.InvoiceDate)
and MONTH(fsivh.InvoiceDate) = 2
) as 'Feb',
from sqlinvline fsivlo , sqlinvheader fsivho
where fsivlo.HeaderKey = fsivho.InvoiceHeaderKey
and fsivho.InvoiceType = 'I'
and year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) >= year(DATEadd(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()))
group by YEAR(fsivho.InvoiceDate)
order by Month1
```

(I've shortened the code for brevity but the other months are formatted the same way)

When I run it, I get multiple lines for the years with an entry for a value against each month and the rest as nulls...e.g.

year jan  feb  mar  apr  etc
2014 nul  1    nul  nul
2014   6  nul  nul  nul
2014 nul  nul    7  nul

etc

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your data look like. Why cant you use `pivot`?

Comment: i've tried using pivot but no matter how i frame it i always get format errors with the pivot command. data is as in the sql - header lines with invoice date linked to invoice lines with values. tried using group on the year but that fails too.

Answer (score 0):

all sorted by rewriting the query after many hours looking at pivot examples.

```
SELECT * from 
(select year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) as Yr, cast(datename(MONTH     ,fsivho.InvoiceDate) as CHAR(3)) as Mth,
cast(fsivlo.ShipQuantity * fsivlo.InvoiceLocalUnitPrice as decimal(8,2)) as Value
from ARInvoiceLine fsivlo , ARInvoiceHeader fsivho
where fsivlo.HeaderKey = fsivho.HeaderKey
and fsivho.InvoiceType = 'I'
and year(fsivho.InvoiceDate) >= year(DATEadd(yyyy, -4, GETDATE()))) src
PIVOT
(sum(Value)
for Mth in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])) as pvt
order by Yr;
```

so now have rows of years with months across the top and values in the correct place!